# Meaning of "read-only" and "mounting" when talking about MTD

Tags: linux

[This reprinted article from *Linux Magazine*](http://free-electrons.com/blog/managing-flash-storage-with-linux/) talks about MTD and how its partitions work. These partitions are apparently defined on the kernel command line with the parameter `mtdparts`. The article says that MTD partitions can be declared "read-only", but typically partitions are "read-only" in the context of mounting them at some path. I've also read other literature about Android hacking that discuss flash partitions, sometimes saying ([as is done here](http://www.strazzere.com/blog/2009/11/an-update-on-the-archos-5-android-rooting/)) that a partition representing the bootloader is "mounted" read-only despite not being a filesystem. This leads me to wonder what "mounting" means when speaking of flash partitions. Does it mean creating device files that represent them or does it mean mounting them at a mount point?